# Rails: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: text -> unknown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, search, casting

I'm trying to search an array field, an array of hashes like:

```
[{"name" => "1", "no" => 2}, {"name" => "2", "no" => "3"}]
```

This is my query:

```
Trip.mybookings(:passengers, :name, current_user.id)
```

And this is the scope:

```
scope :mybookings, ->(column, key, value) { where("? = ANY (SELECT unnest(\"#{column}\") -> ?)", value, key) }
```

But I get this error:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text -> unknown
LINE 1: ...ps" WHERE ('1' = ANY (SELECT unnest("passengers") -> 'name')...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT "trips".* FROM "trips" WHERE ('1' = ANY (SELECT unnest("passengers") -> 'name'))
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text -> unknown
LINE 1: ...ps" WHERE ('1' = ANY (SELECT unnest("passengers") -> 'name')...
```

I don't know which attribute should be casted and how to do this? In fact, I don't know why I should do this?!

Any idea?

Comment: The `passengers` column appears to be of type `text`. Try casting it to `json` or `jsonb` (or change the column's data type).

Comment: @Marth I think it should be text, because it's PostgreSQL's array.

Comment: @Marth And let me know please how can I cast it to json?

Comment: So `passengers` is a `text[]` column but your somehow storing an array of hashes in it? What exactly do these hashes look like inside the database? By "inside the database" I mean ignore all the Rails stuff and look at the column values using `psql` to talk directly to the database.

Comment: @muistooshort I defined it as text, array: true to use the power of arrays in Postgresql. I need it like a pair of two values (or two key/value). So, I can store it as I want. I tried it like an array of hashes to facilitate the search, but it doesn't work. It's like [{"name" => "1", "no" => 2}, {"name" => "2", "no" => "3"}] as I told in the question. Anything else?

Comment: @muistooshort It is stored like this: `["{\"name\"=>\"1\", \"no\"=>\"2\"}"]` , I don't know why?! But as I told, I can store it in a different way if it's needed.

Comment: Stop trying to be fancy with arrays and JSON columns. Break that data out into a separate table so that you can do simple JOINs and things that ActiveRecord is comfortable with.